# Webpage in different directory off the Root

Tags: subsites

I have Drupal (Ver. 6) installed in the Root directory.

I would like to have a page on my website be loaded from another sub-directory off the root. How do I go about doing this and make sure the page uses my theme?

ie.

www.mydomain.com/state/statepage

Thanks-in-Advance,

John

Comment: If you mean you want to include a static HTML file, or outside-of-Drupal PHP file, and have it magically integrate with Drupal and its theme system, I'm afraid you're out of luck. You'll need to convert the functionality so it happens inside Drupal (see [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)). Sorry if I've misunderstood though.

Comment: Do you want to add a simple page and maybe edit the path alias? Or do you want a second Drupal instance in a sub folder?

Comment: Just a simple page, but it needs to use the main websites custom theme